# how to convert * to 000 in currency textbox?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, currency

I have currency text box in asp.net 
I use :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Comma(Num) { //function to add commas to textboxes
        Num += '';
        Num = Num.replace(',', ''); Num = Num.replace(',', ''); Num = Num.replace(',', '');
        Num = Num.replace(',', ''); Num = Num.replace(',', ''); Num = Num.replace(',', '');
        x = Num.split('.');
        x1 = x[0];
        x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
        var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
        while (rgx.test(x1))
            x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
        return x1 + x2;
    }
</script>
```

and

```
  <asp:TextBox ID="amountTextBox" runat="server" onkeyup = "javascript:this.value=Comma(this.value);"></asp:TextBox>
```

it works and hasn't any problem, but I want when user press *, instead of * be written  '000' in text box. how to do this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this is what you need

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Comma(Num) { //function to add commas to textboxes
        if (Num.indexOf("*") != -1) {

            Num = document.getElementById('amountTextBox').value.substring(0, Num.indexOf("*")) + '000';
        }
        Num += '';
        Num = Num.replace(',', ''); Num = Num.replace(',', ''); Num = Num.replace(',', '');
        Num = Num.replace(',', ''); Num = Num.replace(',', ''); Num = Num.replace(',', '');
        x = Num.split('.');
        x1 = x[0];
        x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
        var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
        while (rgx.test(x1))
            x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
        return x1 + x2;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. I try it, but , for example , when I write 12*  all text convert to 000. I want that text convert to 12,000 .have you other solution?

Comment: Thanks a lot , but this not work. please help me. I don't know any things about java script.

Comment: Hey friend, I just tested and it works ... what error you see?

Comment: when I type 1212* it convert to 1,212* and * not convert to 000

Comment: when I type 1212* it convert to 1,212,000. look, what browser are you use? you must press F12 and open the console and execute the program and see in the error console the problem. Make sure you are copying the code exactly same. this line is the most important "Num = document.getElementById('amountTextBox').value.substring(0, Num.indexOf("*")) + '000';" (sorry for my english)

Comment: I use Firefox and noting event and when use IE exception is occurred ,with error : JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference

Comment: It is very rare. look, send me a email and I response you with my example project (nacho69305@hotmail.com) (or tell me where I can send you)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I use :   Num=Num.replace('*','000') ,and it works correctly.